# Accessing server values in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

EDIT: Forgot a piece of code when taking stuff that was relevant

I want to work with the "jsonData" value from my server in my javascript file, but i don't know how to get the values there?

server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
var Amadeus = require('amadeus');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.listen(8080);

app.get('/hotels', function(req, res){

    var searchTerm = req.query.cityCode;

    amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
        cityCode: searchTerm
    }).then(function(response){

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);
        var output = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++){
            output+= "Name: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData.data[i].hotel.name) + "\t";
            output+= "Rating: " + JSON.stringify(jsonData.data[i].hotel.rating) + "\t";  
        }
        res.render('pages/onestar', {jsonData: output});

    }).catch(function(error){

      console.log(error.response); //=> The response object with (un)parsed data
      //console.log(error.response.request); //=> The details of the request made
      console.log(error.code); //=> A unique error code to identify the type of error
    });
});
```

JavaScript attempt that i have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchbutton').submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('xxxxxx', function(jsonData){
           console.log(jsonData); 
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Are you sending some data in `res` at all? What result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send something back from your express server program to the web browser. There are [lots of methods on the `res` object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) to do that.

Replace

```
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);
```

with

```
  res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(response.body))
```

You could also send back the JSON text in the `response.body` directly rather than parsing it first, only to tell express to stringify it again. But the `req.json()` function also sets the Content-Type header on the response to the web browser so it knows it's getting JSON. With respect, that's a little complex for your apparent present level of understanding. Keep it in mind for a later optimization when you get your code working.